# What is the point of monster level?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I've already read [this](http://www.finalfantasyforums.net/showthread.php?t=42006) and came to believe it does **not** really answer the question, not more than any other guess.

So I ask here: is there, and if there is what is the purpose of the monster level in Final Fantasy 13 game? I don't think it's just random, but can't figure its meaning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enemy levels determine the target time for a battle, and consequently, these post-battle stats:

- Points per second
- Score
- Stars
- TP recovery
- Item and shroud drop chance

Based on the [Game Mechanics guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/928790-final-fantasy-xiii/faqs/59246) on GameFAQs:

---

#### Target time

Given:

- Target time **T**
- HP at start of battle **H**
- Enemy level **L**
- Highest party member attack power **Ap**
- ATB level **A**

Thus:

```
 T = (H * L / 16) / [(Ap * A) / (3.5 + A)] + 8
```

if enemy level **L** is less than or equal to 50, otherwise:

```
 T = (H * 50 / 16) / [(Ap * A) / (3.5 + A)] + 8
```

---

#### Points per second

Given:

- Points per second **P**
- Target time **T**

Thus:

```
 P = 10,000 / T
```

---

#### Score

Given:

- Score **S**
- Points per second **P**
- Target time **T**
- Battle duration **D**

Thus:

```
 S = (T - D) * P + 10,000
```

---

#### Stars, TP recovery, rare drop chance, shroud drop chance

```
  Score           | Stars |  TP  | Rare | Shroud 
 ================================================
  > 13,000        |   5   |   8x |   5x |    1x           
  12,000 - 12,999 |   4   |   3x |   3x |    1x           
  9,000 - 11,999  |   3   |   1x |   1x |    1x           
  8,000 - 8,999   |   2   | 1/2x |   0  |    2x               
  7,000 - 7,999   |   1   | 1/4x |   0  |    4x               
  < 7,000         |   0   | 1/8x |   0  |    8x
```

Comment: Nice one, my mistake was searching for "monster level" instead of "enemy level" - thanks! :)